# What is the best approach for creating a controller in Kubernetes?

Tags: go, kubernetes

I'm not quite sure if which of the following approaches is the better approach to create a controller in kubernetes however I know that:

- I don't want to create a custom resource by any means.
- I do only want to fetch information about k8s native resources (pods, ...) given that there might be a lot of pods in each namespace

I have seens some patterns like:

```
ctrl, err := controller.New("name-here", mgr, controller.Options{
    Reconciler: &ReconcilePod{Client: mgr.GetClient(), Logger: log},
})
```

which `ReconcilePod` is a struct that has a function `Reconcile` that keep whole business logic.

Another approach I have seens is like following:

```
type Controller struct {
    indexer  cache.Indexer
    queue    workqueue.RateLimitingInterface
    informer cache.Controller
}
```

and then defining `shared informer` and `watcher` etc.
And the third pattern that I have seen is using `operators`

what I don't get perhaps is what is the main differences between mentioned approaches above and which one fits my need at scale.

Comment: Do you want to "control" something, or do you just want to "watch" and "read"?

Comment: I just want to watch and read

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to "control" anything, there is no need to create a *controller*.

If you just want to "read" and "watch" resources, you can use [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) and see e.g. [Extend Kubernetes via a shared informer](https://www.cncf.io/blog/2019/10/15/extend-kubernetes-via-a-shared-informer/) for inspiration about how to *read* and *watch* resources.

> To stay informed about when these events get triggered you can use a primitive exposed by Kubernetes and the client-go called SharedInformer, inside the cache package. Let’s see how it works in practice.

Controllers are more complex and contains a *reconciliation loop* since they should realize/manage a *desired state*.

An "operator" is a *controller* as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply start with operator-sdk provided to create a controller easily in which the code will be generated and you need to add business logic to your objects. https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/golang/quickstart/

```
mkdir memcached-operator
cd memcached-operator
operator-sdk init --domain example.com --repo github.com/example/memcached-operator
```

You can simply then create controller eith for existing kind or a new kind

```
operator-sdk create api --group cache --version v1alpha1 --kind Memcached --resource --controller
```

It is the simplest way to manage kinds and resources using operator sdk and no need to worry about complex code of client set